# Not able to retrive data from Facebook apprequest

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am using new facebook sdk 3.0 to send app request and some data along with it. I can successfully send request. In FB app I can see notification of request but when I click on request FB app redirect me to my app but I dont get any data.

In

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

function I print url it says -

> "{type = 15, string =
>   fb170873116339908://authorize#expires_in=0&access_token=BAACbaH9mrsQBAP2nmjqTdOzQPezetH2Y5sZAMXjXRPZB3nSSKBRD8lgdOY4OoU8mNl4Jeh3KVZCApYxESBfgQ7bRHsZCYtZAV9vDOyx5yDTCttWMoGKZAQ5eiErRTCyU4ZD&target_url=http%3A%2F%2Fapps%2Efacebook%2Ecom%2Fapps%2Fapplication%2Ephp%3Fid%{FB
>   APP ID}, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}"

I also search for answer and found out that mobile app cannot sen data along with appreques. Is this true? If not can some one help me with tutorial or example.

and also can some one confirm [that tutorial is working or not?](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/#protip1)

Comment: in target_url i am getting http://apps.facebook.com/apps/application.php/?id={FB APP ID} only. after above url I should get ref=notif but I dont get any other parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your FB app providing you url of you canvas app. May be you have entered wrong Url schema suffix in FB app settings. you will find  "Url schema suffix" listed under native IOS app tab.

I also encountered same problem and I delete all Url schema suffix.
Hope this may help you.

Comment: Yep, worth checking that you've read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/link-to-your-native-app-ios-sdk/ for configuring deep linking correctly

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the `data` field isn't sent when the user accepts the request, you need to make an API call to /REQUEST_ID to retrieve the details of the request - the `data` value you provided should be present in the response, then you can delete the request as normal

If you don't have the request ID either, a call to `/me/apprequests` will show you all requests that user has yet to accept for your app